# Architecture 32 bits

Tags: memory, architecture

In an architecture 32 bits, a pointer is 4 bytes length and a double is 8 bytes length. But why, in this architecture, the pointer is not 8 bytes length like double ?
Which would allow a wider addressing like in 64 bits architecture !

Answer (score 0):

It is, you are trying to make generalities where they can't be made.

You have to look at each specific processor architecture.  You have to look at the instructions that can for example do register based addressing, whatever term that architecture uses, register indirect or whatever.  My processor may have 32 bit general purpose registers and all read and write/load and store transactions must use a general purpose register, so on the surface my processor is likely limited to 4Gbytes of address space, 32 bit address, byte addressable memory.  Some don't actually support that so you have to keep reading the docs, but they can't without other solutions address more than that.  So then if I were to write a C compiler for this processor then the sane approach would be to have 32 bit pointers.

It would not in anyway stated so far be possible to generate a 64 bit address.  Even though for some reason Intel got beat up for what is very commonly done then and now, by adding more address bits in another location, segmenting the architecture is quite common.  You most often would see this in the 16 bit architectures (like 8086 as well as others), where they wanted to get beyond a 64Kbyte limit for the whole system.  You need to create a solution for the extra address bits, you could do a double register instruction where the address comes from two registers either double width making a 32 bit address or offset some say one is shifted left 8 and added to the other making a 24 or like Intel one is shifted 4 and added, making 20. Now Intel didn't use a general purpose register but a special purpose one and that was also not uncommon, others may force a whole bank switch so unlike Intel's wise approach where the same external address can be accessed in 16 different ways internally, you can only access isolated 64Kbyte address spaces making the programming more difficult.

It is like saying my car has four wheels why can't I just have 8 wheels and drive in two lanes at the same time.  Because that is a different car.  If you want a processor to have 32 bit registers but have a 64 bit address space, that is quite possible but you need to design it at the architectural level and provide instructions or other solutions to allow those transactions, and to be sane enough of a design that you could create a high level language compiler like C for it and not rely on only assembly language programmers using it.

Documentation is freely available for x86 (8088/86, 386, and so on), ARM, MIPSs, RISC-V, AVR, and on and on.  These documents in some form show how addressing works especially the older/smaller architectures that were trying to use an address bus wider than a single register could hold.  Those often used pictures/diagrams to show how the address is created.